# Office365 developer account

Tags: office365

I can't find any info regarding Office 365 developer account. Does anyone know if MS is offering free developer account for Office 365?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, Microsoft doesn't offer any kind of developer account. Just create an account and start developing against your office365 instance.

In general you do SharePoint Development on your local box you need your office365 instance the first time when you're going to deploy your solution.